# Python NameError when importing functions from other files

Tags: python

For example, I have the following source files:
file `a.py`

```
from b import *

def A():
    print 'function A'
    B()
    return
```

file `b.py`

```
from a import *

def B():
    print 'function B'
    A()
    return

def main():
    A()
    B()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I run `python b.py`, I met with the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'A' is not defined
```

The full message, together with prints is as follows:

```
function A
function B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "b.py", line 9, in main
    A()
  File "/home/mypath/a.py", line 5, in A
    B()
  File "/home/mypath/b.py", line 5, in B
    A()
NameError: global name 'A' is not defined
```

What's wrong with it?
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: You have `circle` import problem

Comment: @luoluo Is it not allowed?

Comment: @pfc Not in Python, no.  When you import a module, all of the code in that module is run.  A imports B which imports A which imports B which imports...

Comment: @MackM Wrong.  Circular imports *are* allowed in Python and work with careful programming.  I have done it.  Idlelib has circular imports, but careless movements of imports can disable IDLE.  If sys.modules['a'] does not exist, `sys.modules['a'] = new_module()` is done first.  Then the code in a.py is executed to fill in the module.  If a.py has an import statement, then the execution of a.py is interrupted by a recursive call to the internal import function.  If every recursive call returns, then the circular imports are ok.